# Customizing Slick Generator

Tags: scala, slick

I'm using the Slick generator to generate my tabble definitions based on my database and I would like to change a thing in the generated code.
When it generates the classes it does not put my auto increment keys as Option[Int] = None in the case classes... Is there a way to do that?
And maybe add an autoinc method in the table definition that returns the generated id like this for example:

```
def autoInc = id.? ~ name <> (User, User.unapply _) returning id
```

Comment: did you find the way on how to add a new method in a TableClass? I do not know what should be override and what should be put. I'm thinking a class with trait Def

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea

Comment: Ah its ok, I already got the answer ;) While playing with slick ,  you need to create a new Def then append it in the definitions (depends on where you want it) either in  TableClassDef or TableDef or in other parts.

Comment: Here is the example https://gist.github.com/avramirez/87556be9ddd3e1fbdf4b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code generator already supports this. You have to set `autoIncLastAsOption = true`.

```
new SourceCodeGenerator(model){
    override def Table = new Table(_){
        override def autoIncLastAsOption = true
    }
}
```

Also see http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0/code-generation.html for more help with customizing the code generator.

Comment: thanks a lot. Do you know if its possible to generate the method to return the inserted key?

Comment: You could override `def Column` in the same way and override `def code` within the `Column` object to append it. It may make sense to put it in the user code instead.

Comment: I'm having a problem when I use this aproach. It generates things like this `import positional._ 
UserRow.tupled((_2, _3, _4, _5, _1)) // putting AutoInc last` and for table that has more than 22 columns (max number of itens of a tupple) it generates a compilation error because it generates like this `import positional._
    r(1) :: r(2) :: r(3) :: // and so on` Do you know what is causing this?

Comment: Looks like a bug. Please try if it still happens with 2.0.1-RC1 and if it does, please submit a bug report at https://github.com/slick/slick

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22324675/compilation-error-with-slick-for-table-22-columns-using-hlists/22326731#22326731