# Slick code generator - primary key as option

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I'm using slick code generator for generating classes from SQL database in Play for scala 2.4. I'm wondering how to generate code with primary key defined as `Option`, so when I'm inserting new record I can put `None` instead of primary key.

Let's suppose that I have a table

```
OrderItem
----------
orderItemId: int
name: varchar
```

For now I have to create instance like this:

```
val item = new OrderItem(0, "Item name")
db.run(orderItems += item)
```

It works, but the zero is just odd, so my goal is

```
val item = new OrderItem(None, "Item name")
db.run(orderItems += item)
```

Is that possible? With PK of type `Option[Int]` I should then also be able to reuse this class e.g. for forms mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [example in slick documentation](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0-RC1/code-generation.html) just change `rawType` to

```
    override def rawType = {
      if (model.options.contains(ColumnOption.PrimaryKey)) {
        "Option[" + super.rawType + "]"
      } else {
        super.rawType
      }
    }
```

**Update**

My question is a duplicate: [Customizing Slick Generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22275022/customizing-slick-generator)

Slick code generator already implements this:

```
new SourceCodeGenerator(model){
    override def Table = new Table(_){
        override def autoIncLastAsOption = true
    }
}
```